# Addition of kmllayer blocks out the map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3, kml

When using the Google Maps API, I am having troubles adding the KML Layer.

Using the following javascript, the map renders fine.

```
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.754,-115.834),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    //var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://forestcrowne.ca/earth/dave.kml');
    //ctaLayer.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

When I uncomment the ctaLayer, the map disappears (yesterday it would render the kml file, but the map still disappeared). What is happening?

Take a look:
http://forestcrowne.ca/?page_id=1647 - with ctaLayer commented 
http://forestcrowne.ca/?page_id=1668 - with ctaLayer uncommented

Answer (score 0):

The KmlLayer displays [fine when not on your page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linkto.html?filename=http://forestcrowne.ca/earth/dave.kml).  Try not using the "experimental/nightly build" version of the API, change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&#038;sensor=false"></script>
```

To call out a specific version (or v=3)

Comment: Thanks for this, even though it does not fix it. It does help me; I now know my code works, just not in Wordpress - and I'm not going crazy. I just changed all my variable names, just because - still the same. Still stuck...

Comment: If it is in wordpress, look at the css that is being applied to the map.

Comment: I am using very little and it works on the map that I am not adding the KML layer

Comment: <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div> this is the css

Comment: Wordpress has lots of external css files, one of the styles from those is being applied to the map when the KmlLayer is displayed.

Comment: How the heck does one trouble shoot that? There are no styles referencing map_canvas, ctaLayer, KmlLayer or map. I can't see how the styles that style the container and wrapper, could effect the map differently when the kml layer is added. The idea is kind of appealing, but when I look at it, I can't see how.

Comment: Plus, when you look at it, the map controls etc. are all visible. I am not overlaying something over the entire map div. Something is happening within the map. Still thinking...

Comment: You debug styles using developer tools (built into most web browsers now). One of the offending styles is `.post img {background-color:#f3f3f3;}`.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to all the help - I got it. I changed the background-color to transparent on the "Images in Posts". Atahualpa has some fancy css to create radiused borders on images - one of the properties specified in background-color. So.. it was the css